# Change order of columns when some them are variable (Pandas)

Tags: pandas

I want to change order of my columns (Excel File) but some of the column names are variable(changes every day).
could we assign number to the columns?

Comment: Can you please provide an example with sample input and expected output?

Comment: these are the column names. it is updated every day so that the last column is renamed:                                                                                                                                   dsfg     Bdfg     gfdg    fgh   2020-04-13 2020-04-14 2020-04-15 2020-04-16 2020-04-17 2020-04-18 2020-04-19